# How can I share a dict between two different http requests

Tags: python, django, shared-memory

The Django application loads data from a file to a Python dict, process it and sends it as http response. Now say n number of request are received on the web server then this Django app would run `n` times and load data from a file to a Python dict `n` times. I was wondering if somehow I can make this data being loaded to the dict only once while `n` http response could be served.

An example `view.py` file for the problem situation can be as followed:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest

def hello(request):
    data = open("abc").readlines()
    return HttpResponse(data[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for the [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs/). Add it to your settings and it will persist across your request. Its a better option then persistence and definitely a lot better than using a global object.

*Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input and/or output. Each middleware component is responsible for doing some specific function. For example, Django includes a middleware component, XViewMiddleware, that adds an "X-View" HTTP header to every response to a HEAD request.*

Answer (score 4):

Binding the dictionary to a global name will make it persist for as long as the Django project runs. Note that each Django process (some WSGI containers, e.g. mod_wsgi, can run multiple processes for an app) will have its own independent copy of the dictionary.

Comment: @Torsten: Of *course* it isn't. But that's due to the nature of the question.

Comment: I like your attitude, but shouldn't we suggest users to use better practices? :D

Comment: @Torsten: I don't see you asking him why he wants it in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

If the data is relevant to the user, you can use djanog's [session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to persist data across requests. If the data needs to be shared between numerous users, you can use the [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/).

Comment: Data is irrelevant of user but range of ips from the request has been generated from.